# To prove that a given transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The question is as follows:

> Let $V$ denote the vector space of all real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Define $T_a \colon V\to V$ by
> $(T_a(h))(x) = h(x + a)$, $h \in V$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

> Prove that $T_a$ is a linear operator on $V$

Here we have no information whatsoever about the properties of the transformation, so how do we show that the transformation is linear? We must be given a known property about the transformation in order to proceed, right?

Comment: What do you mean you have "no information"?  You are given the exact definition of the map.  What more could you want?

Comment: $T_a (ch+g)= (ch+g)(x+a)=ch(x+a)+g(x+a)=c T_a(h)+ T_a(g)$.

Comment: I had come across linear transformations very recently, I'm unable to see how I can use the given information to prove that the transformation is linear. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Just go through the axioms one by one.  None of them are difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You were given a function whose domain and codomain are vector spaces. You need to verify whether that function is linear. There is no more "information" that you need, assuming that the vector space structure of your domain and codomain are clear.

So, what are those structures? The elements of $V$ are functions $h\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. The addition of vectors is defined pointwise, so that if $h$ and $g$ are functions, then the function "$h+g$" is defined as follows: (to describe a function, I can just tell you how it is defined on every real number, which is what the equation below does):
$$(h+g)(x) = h(x)+g(x).$$
Note that (i) the $+$ on the left is the sum of vectors in $V$; the $+$  on the right is the sum of real numbers. Same symbol, but *two different operations*! And (ii) this makes sense, because $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both real numbers and we can add them; so this formula tells you how to evaluate "$h+g$" at every real number to get a real number. That is, this formula defines a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Scalar multiplication in $V$ is defined as follows: given a vector $h\in V$ (that is, a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$), and a scalar $c$ (which is, presumably, a real number), the function "$c\cdot h$" is defined by the rule
$$(c\cdot h)(x) = ch(x),$$
where the right hand side is the real number product of the real number $c$ and the real number $h(x)$.

I leave it to you to verify this gives $V$ the structure of a vector space.

So now, we fix a real number $a$. We define an operator $T_a\colon V\to V$. This is an operator that takes functions as inputs, and returns functions as outputs. Given a function $h\in V$, $T_a(h)$ needs to be a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. To describe this function, we tell you what its value is at any given real number $x$. And that definition is:
$$\Bigl(T_a(h)\Bigr)(x) = h(x+a).$$
Again, this makes sense: $x+a$ is a real number, $h$ is a function that takes real numbers as inputs and gives real numbers as outputs, so $h(x+a)$ is a real number. Thus, $T_a(h)$, evaluated at the real number $x$, yields a real number. That is, $T_a(h)$ is in fact a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and so is an element of $V$.

So $T_a$ defines an operator form $V$ to itself. Now you want to prove that it is a linear operator. That is, you need to verify that:

1. $T_a(h+g) = T_a(h)+T_a(g)$; and
2. $T_a(c\cdot h) = c\cdot T_a(h)$.

This requires you to verify equalities of *functions*. Two functions are equal when they have the same domain, the same codomain, and the same value at every point of the domain. These are all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so you just need to verify they take the same value at every real number. So you need to check that, for every real number $x$, the result you get from evaluating
$$\Bigl(T_a(h+g)\Bigr)(x)$$
is the same as the result you get from evaluating
$$\Bigl(T_a(h)\Bigr)(x) + \Bigl(T_a(g)\Bigr)(x).$$
This will require you to unwind a few definitions.

Similarly, you need to verify that evaluating
$$\Bigl( T_a(c\cdot h)\Bigr)(x)$$
gives the same result as evaluating
$$\Bigl(c\cdot T_a(h)\Bigr)(x).$$
Again, this requires unwinding a few definitions.

If you get equalities, you have proven $T_a$ is a linear operator.

You have all the information required.